# Is there a GET equivalent to Set-PnPListItemPermission?

Tags: item-level-permissions

I am trying to get a list of all the users that have been granted special permission to a list of files inside a library. I was able to set the permission using Set-PnpListItemPerission but can't seem to find the reverse anywhere.

Can anyone suggest a way of listing all the users and permissions granted for a file (list item) in a library? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using default Get-PnPListItem

```
Get-PnPListItem -List Tasks -Id 1
```

Once you have get objec of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem

This object has RoleAssignments Properties which will give you collection of RoleAssignment object. This object will have collections of user having permission on this item. you can use RoleAssignment.Member property to get actual user details of type Principal.

You can refer to below code sample on how to loop through loop RoleAssigments and get users having access. This is nto exact code, but it will get you idea on hwo to retrieve these properties.

```
$file = Get-PnPListItem -List Tasks -Id 1
        Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $file -Property HasUniqueRoleAssignments, RoleAssignments

        if($file.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True) 
        {
            foreach($roleAssignments in $file.RoleAssignments )  
            {
                Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $roleAssignments -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member

                $permission.LoginName = $roleAssignments.Member.LoginName
                $permission.LoginTitle = $roleAssignments.Member.Title
                $permission.PrincipalType = $roleAssignments.Member.PrincipalType.ToString()
                $permission.Permission = ""
                #Get the Permissions assigned to user 
                foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $roleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings) 
                { 
                    $permission.Permission = $permission.Permission + "," + $RoleDefinition.Name 
                }
            }
        }
```

You can also use REST API..

> "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/
>         items(1)?$expand=RoleAssignments/Member/Users"